# Exit animations not working with framer motion

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

This is my App.js

```
import Services from './components/Services';
import { Main } from 'components/Main';
import React from 'react';
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from 'components/Navbar';
import DrycleaningServices from 'pages/Drycleaning';
import ScrollToTop from 'components/ScrollToTop';
import Footer from 'components/Footer';
import Portfolio from 'pages/Portfolio';

const App = () => {
  const location = useLocation(); 

  return (
    <>
      <motion.div initial="hidden" animate="show">
        <Navbar />
        <AnimatePresence mode='wait'>
          <Routes key={location.pathname} location={location}>
            <Route  path="/drycleaning" element={<DrycleaningServices />} />
            <Route path="/services" element={<Services />} />
            <Route path="/portfolio" element={<Portfolio />} />
            <Route path="/" element={<Main />} />
          </Routes>
        </AnimatePresence>
        <ScrollToTop />
      </motion.div>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This is my page component

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import play from '../assets/play.png';
import { servicesAnimation } from 'animation';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import  banner  from '../assets/drycleaning-banner.jpg'
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import AnimatedPage from 'components/AnimatedPage';


function DrycleaningServices() {

  const transition = {duration: 3, ease: [0.43, 0.13, 0.23, 0.96 ]}
  
  return (
  <AnimatedPage><Section id="inner-page">
    <div className='banner'></div>
    <div className="inner">
      
      
        
            <motion.div>
              
              <div className="inner__service__title">
                <h2>Dry Cleaning</h2>
              </div>
              <p className="inner-description"><a href='/'>tet=sssssst </a>We specialize in providing exceptional dry cleaning services to keep your wardrobe looking pristine. Dry cleaning is a meticulous process that goes beyond traditional laundering methods, employing a solvent-based technique to gently and effectively remove stains from delicate fabrics. Our experienced team understands the unique requirements of different materials and garments, ensuring that each item receives the care and attention it deserves.</p>
              
              <p className="inner-description">We specialize in providing exceptional dry cleaning services to keep your wardrobe looking pristine. Dry cleaning is a meticulous process that goes beyond traditional laundering methods, employing a solvent-based technique to gently and effectively remove stains from delicate fabrics. Our experienced team understands the unique requirements of different materials and garments, ensuring that each item receives the care and attention it deserves.</p>
              
              <p className="inner-description">In addition to our dry cleaning services, we offer alterations and repairs to ensure your clothes fit perfectly. Our skilled tailors can handle everything from simple adjustments to intricate alterations, providing you with a personalized and comfortable fit. Experience the convenience and excellence of [Your Business Name] Dry Cleaners – where your garments receive the care they deserve, and you can confidently step out in style.</p>
              <img src={play} alt="Read More" />
            </motion.div>
          
        
      

    </div>

    
  </Section>
  </AnimatedPage>
  )
  
}

const Section = styled.section`
min-height: 100vh;
.inner{
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 14rem;
  margin-top: 10rem;
  gap: 5rem;
  &__service{
    padding: 2rem;
    &:nth-of-type(2) {
      
      .inner__service__title{
        span{
          color: #fff;

        }
      }
      
    }
    &__image{
      margin-bottom: 3rem;
    }
    &__title{
      span{
        color: var(--primary-color);
        font-weight: bolder;
      } 
      h2{
        font-size: 3rem;
        line-height: 2.5rem;
        margin-bottom: 5rem;
        color: var(--secondary-color);
      }    
    }
    &__description{
      color: var(--primary-color);
      margin-bottom: 2rem;

    }
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
    .services {
      
      padding-top: 5rem;
      
    }
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 280px) and  (max-width: 1080px){
    .services{
      margin: 2rem 0;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      gap: 2rem;
      padding: 0 2rem;
    }
  }
  .banner{
    background-image: url(${banner});
    background-position: center;
    height: 20rem;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .inner-description{
       margin-bottom: 2rem;
      }
`;

export default DrycleaningServices;
```

This is my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

All other animations are working including the loading page ones but exit animation is not working when I move to another page. I looked everywhere including chatGPT but nothing works. Even on a simple page with just enter and exit animation the exit doesnt fire